# Scraping and downloading images without a File Extension

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to use Scrapy's Image/File `pipeline` to download images without any file extension.

For example, this image:

https://burpple-2.imgix.net/foods/3d9294008d0f76a92e21647960_original.?w=400&h=400&fit=crop&q=80

As you can see, the image loads just fine, and I'm able to scrape the url in `Scrapy`. However, passing the url to `image_urls` or `file_urls` yield no downloaded images.

I've tried appending ".jpg" to the end of the url, it doesn't work.

How would I download these kind of images?

EDIT:

I have already enabled `ImagePipeline`. Downloading from other URLs with proper file extension to them works fine, and I can see the images are downloaded to the designated folders.

Comment: Why do you think that this file has no extension? For me it appears as `image/jpeg` file

Comment: @Andersson Well yes it is jpeg. But somehow scrapy is unable to download it even as I append .jpg or .jpeg at the end of the url. Other website with proper image url works fine, so I don't think it's any issue with my configuration.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with image as well. I can easily download the file

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled the [ImagePipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-images-pipeline) in your settings?

You should be able to see an INFO log that looks like this:

```
2018-11-14 10:37:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline']
```

This code worked for me:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

class MySpider(Spider):

    name = "burpple-2.imgix.net"
    start_urls = ['https://burpple-2.imgix.net/']

    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},
        'IMAGES_STORE': '/some/valid/folder/',
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'image_urls': ['https://burpple-2.imgix.net/foods/3d9294008d0f76a92e21647960_original.?w=400&h=400&fit=crop&q=80'],
        }
```

Comment: Did you see the image actually downloaded to the folder? I've already enabled `ImagePipeline`, and other websites with proper image url can be downloaded just fine.

Comment: Yes, I can see the image downloaded locally in the folder, it created a subfolder called `full` and the image was in there.